# Tkinter music player

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried making a music player with tkinter in python but there's an error about module not callable but I'm not able to fix it. Can someone help?

````
import tkinter as Tk
import pygame 
import os


def __init__(self,root):
    self.root = root
    # title of the window
    self.root.title("MusicPlayer")
    # window geometry
    self.root.geometry("1000x200+200+200")
    # initiating pygame
    pygame.init()
    # initiating pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.init()
    # declaring track variable
    self.track = StringVar()
    # Declaring status variable
    self.status = StringVar() 

    #creating the track frames for song label & status label
    trackframe = LabelFrame(self.root,text='Song Track',font=('times new roman',15,'bold'),bg='Navyblue',fg='white',bd='5',relief=GROOVE)
    trackframe.place(x=0,y=0,width=600,height=100)
    # inserting song track label
    songtrack = Label(trackframe,textvariable=self.track,width=20,font=('time new roman',24,'bold'),bg='orange',fg='gold').grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=5)
    # inserting status label
    trackstatus = Label(trackframe,textvariable=self.status,font=('times new roman',24,'bold'),bf='orange',fg='gold').grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)

    # creating button frame
    buttonframe = LabelFrame(self.root,text='control panel',font=('times new roman',15,'bold'),bg='grey',fg='white',bd=5,relief=GROOVE)
    buttonframe.place(x=0,y=100,widht=600,height=100)
    # inserting play button
    playbtn = Button(buttonframe, text='PLAYSONG',command=self.playsong,width=10,height=1,font=('times new roman',16,'bold'),fg='navyblue',bg='pink').grid(row=0,cloumn=0,padx=10,pady=5)
    # inserting pause button
    #this might need to be renamed
    playbtn = Button(buttonframe,text='PAUSE',command=self.pausesong,widht=8,height=1,font=('times new roman',16,'bold'),fg='navyblue',bg='pink').grid(row=0,cloumn=1,padx=10,pady=5)
    # inserting unpause button
    playbtn = Button(buttonframe,text='UNPAUSE',command=self.unpausesong,widht=10,height=1,font=('times new roman',16,'bold'),fg='navyblue',bg="pink").grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10,pady=5)
    # Inserting Stop Button
    playbtn = Button(buttonframe,text="STOPSONG",command=self.stopsong,width=10,height=1,font=("times new roman",16,"bold"),fg="navyblue",bg="pink").grid(row=0,column=3,padx=10,pady=5)

    # creating playlist frame
    songsframe = LabelFrame(self.root, text="Song Playlist",font=('times new roman',15,'bold'),bg='grey',fg='white',bd=5,relief=GROOVE)
    songsframe.place(x=600,y=0,wodht=400,height=200)
    # inserting scrollbar
    scrol_y = Scrollbar(songsframe, orient=VERTICAL)
    # Inserting playlist listbox
    self.playlist = Listbox(songsframe, yscrollcommand=scrol_y.set, selectbackground='gold',selectmode=SINGLE,font=('times new roman',12,'bold'),bg='silver',fg='navyblue',bd=5,relief=GROOVE)
    # applying scrollbar to listbox
    scrol_y.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    scrol_y.config(command=self.playlist.yview)
    self.playlist.pack(fill=BOTH)
    # changing directory for fethcing songs
    os.chdir('D:\python\music_player\songs')
    # FETCHING SONGS
    songstracks = os.listdir()
    # inserting songs into playlist
    for track in songtracks:
        self.playlist.insert(END,track)

def playsong(self):
    # displaying selected song title
    self.track.set(self.playlist.get(ACTIVE))
    # displaying status
    self.status.set('-Playing')
    # loading selected song
    pygame.mixer.music.load(self.playlist.get(ACTIVE))
    # PLAYING selected song
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

def stopsong(self):
    # displaying status
    self.status.set('-Stopped')
    # stopped song
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()

def pausesong(self):
    # displaying status
    self.status.set('-Paused')
    # paused song
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()

def unpausesong(self):
    # it will display the status
    self.status.set('-Playing')
    # playing back song
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()

root = Tk() # In order to create an empty window
# Passing Root to MusicPlayer Class
MusicPlayer(root)

root.mainloop()
```
````

Answer (score 3):

> `imported tkinter as Tk`

> `root = Tk() # In order to create an empty window`

You imported tkinter under the name Tk, which coincidentally matches with the `Tk()` class of the tkinter module. By doing `Tk()` you are basically calling `tkinter()`, which is not a valid method or function.

I suggest you use `import tkinter as tk` instead.